# make-operator returns swindleobject

Tags: scheme, racket, clos

```
#lang swindle
(require swindle/misc
         swindle/setf
     )


(defclass* jacket ()
  (size :initvalue 40 :accessor sj)
  :printer #t)

(defclass* trousers ()
  (size :initvalue 44 :accessor st)
  :printer #t)

(defclass* suit (jacket trousers)
```

If i compile this code and write (make suit) | (make jacket) | make (trousers) into the interpreter, the return is always `#<procedure:swindleobj>` but it should be sth like `#<jacket size=40>`.

Did I miss any requires or what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is working for me:

```
#lang swindle
(defclass* jacket () (size :initvalue 40 :accessor sj) :printer #t)
(define x (make jacket))

(displayln x)
=> #<jacket: size=40>

(displayln (slot-ref x 'size))
=> 40

(displayln (sj x))
=> 40
```

Comment: ah, that display does the trick. thank you so much, im just a beginner in using swindle :)